# Why is autoindent not applied to my markdown files?

Tags: indentation, filetype-markdown

When editing markdown (`*.md`) formatted files, and making bullet points, upon pressing return I want the new bullet point to be automatically created in the same level under the previous one.

Fortunately, `:set autoindent` does exactly this. However, I shouldn't have to specify it manually according to my [`~/.vimrc`](http://vi.kpaste.net/231abd6cb?raw) (note the `filetype plugin indent on` line and please excuse my horrible config).

I've tested it also with HTML and JavaScript formatted files, and found that `autoindent` *is* being applied there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I believe that `:set autoindent` should do what you expect. From [`:help 'autoindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autoindent%27):

> Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing  in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command). If you do not type anything on the new line except  or CTRL-D and then type , CTRL-O or , the indent is deleted again.  Moving the cursor to another line has the same effect, unless the 'I' flag is included in 'cpoptions'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the behavior you want is controlled by the `comments` and `formatoptions` options, which are set to `comments=fb:*,fb:-,fb:+,n:>` and `formatoptions=tcqln` by $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim. Those options are described here:

```
:help 'comments'
:help format-comments
:help 'formatoptions'
:help fo-table
```

To have the next line *not* automatically indented when you press `<Return>` while entering a bullet, you need to remove the `f` flag from the `*` comment definition. The commands to do that without disturbing the other comment definitions are:

```
:set comments-=fb:*
:set comments+=b:*
```

To have a bullet inserted automatically when you press Return, `formatoptions` needs to include the `r` flag. The command to do that is:

```
:set formatoptions+=r
```

You'll need to do those commands *after* those options have been set by the plugin file, so put those commands, without the leading colons, in a file named `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim.

Answer (score 1):

`filetype indent on`, as [the documentation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype-indent-on) says, loads the corresponding indent file for that filetype. That is, it loads `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/<filetype>.vim` (and similarly for other directories in `runtimepath`). And there is [none for `markdown`](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/indent). Compare (well, even though there's nothing to compare) with `indent/go.vim`, which does [set `autoindent`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/go.vim#L18):

```
" C indentation is too far off useful, mainly due to Go's := operator.
" Let's just define our own.
setlocal nolisp
setlocal autoindent
setlocal indentexpr=GoIndent(v:lnum)
setlocal indentkeys+=<:>,0=},0=
```

So, just using `filetype indent on` isn't enough, you have to have `indent/markdown.vim` somewhere in your `runtimepath` set `autoindent`. Therefore, create `~/.vim/indent/markdown.vim`, containing:

```
setlocal autoindent
```

Or just add `set autoindent` to your `vimrc`, if it's useful enough across filetypes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there is no default vim plugin for md file type. Using vundle I add this plugin and it seems to work well:

`gabrielelana/vim-markdown`

Which is the found at github:
https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown

To install using vundle add this line in the vundle config section of your .vimrc

`Plugin 'gabrielelana/vim-markdown'`

To install using pathogen:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle && \
git clone git://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown.git
```

Comment: Ehm, Vim comes with markdown support, and has for a very long time...