# Why does Vim smartindent on one computer and not another?

Tags: indentation

I have the following in my `.vimrc` on both machines:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

And yet, for some reason I only see the [expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234578/5419599) on my Mac, and not on the other computer (which is a Windows 7 box running MobaXterm).

The auto-unindenting after I type `}` is really quite nice, and I'd like it to work in both places.

Is this an issue with a missing "filetype plugin?"  I can't find any directory where "filetype plugins" are stored and I never installed any myself; how does that work, anyway?

The language I was using at the time I noticed the discrepancy was `awk`, and Vim chose the correct syntax highlighting on both machines (based on the `.awk` file extension), but failed to handle the autoindent the way I expected on Windows.

---

I have installed no plugins at all on either machine.  The `.vimrc` is practically empty in each case.  MobaXterm has Vim 7.3.646; the Mac just says 7.3.

Comment: Are you running the same .vimrc on both machines? Are both machines running the same version of Vim? Do you have the same plugins on both machines?

Comment: See http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6145/205 - perhaps it will help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @muru, that does seem relevant—the Mac has a file `awk.vim` in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent` and the MobaXterm seems to have no such file (and a lot fewer syntax files in general).  But how can I fix this?  (I've never installed any plugins at all, just using Vim "out of the box".)

Comment: Files in `$VIMRUNTIME` (`/usr/share/vim/vim73` in the Mac) aren't plugins in the usual sense, they come with Vim, depending on compilation flags, I think. I have never used MobaXterm, but it seems to have GVim available (it's listed in http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html) - maybe try that. Or you can just create `~/.vim/indent/awk.vim` containing `setlocal autoindent`.